# Moving event handlers into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, android, mozilla, fennec

What I basically need to do is attach this code lines to this file. http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/chrome/content/aboutDownloads.js

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {handle_events();}, true);
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {Downloads.uninit();}, false);

function handle_events(){
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {Downloads.init();}, true);
    document.getElementById("contextmenu-open").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.open, false);
    document.getElementById("contextmenu-retry").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.retry, false);
    document.getElementById("contextmenu-remove").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.remove, false);
    document.getElementById("contextmenu-pause").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.pause, false);
    document.getElementById("contextmenu-resume").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.resume, false);
    document.getElementById("contextmenu-cancel").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.cancel, false);
    document.getElementById("contextmenu-removeall").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.removeAll, false);
    }
```

But when I do that, I get a javascript error saying

```
JavaScript Error: "TypeError: aElement is undefined" {file: "chrome://browser/content/aboutDownloads.js" line: 435}
```

Multiple times. How can I fix this?. This is a part of the code from Firefox for android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your method calls in an anonymous function like this:

```
document.getElementById("contextmenu-open").addEventListener("click", ContextMenus.open, false);
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("contextmenu-open").addEventListener("click", function() {ContextMenus.open()}, false);
```

This preserves the `ContextMenus` object as the caller of the method and makes sure that `this` is set properly when the method is called.

---

In addition, I don't think you want to install a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler in 'handle_events()`because`DOMContentLoaded`has already fired at that point since you're calling`handle_events()`from a`DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

For `Downloads.init()`, just call it directly in the first line of `handle_events()`.  The DOM is already loaded so you can just call it, you don't have to wait for an event.

Comment: Done the changes and now building, So how could I fire the Downloads.init() function there? I can't attach the event handler without a event!

Comment: Just call `Downloads.init()` directly in the first line of `handle_events()`.  You don't have to wait for an event because the DOM is already loaded.

Comment: It worked. Previously The Downloads.init() function was also not triggering I think because the `DOMContentLoaded` was already done. I'm marking this as the answer :)